# TypeError: this.getdataSource is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to allow EDITS on my API data list. It allows me to Edit the list entry, however when I submit the edition, I get an error saying that

```
   `this.getDataSource();`
```

is not a function. I have trying to debug this for some time but am having no luck.

Also, if someone had some advice or guidance on how to go about making this a fully operation CRUD application that allows for new entries to be POST back to the API and also allows for the editions to be PUT back into that API that would be great. I am unsure if I have to modify my fetch request or if I am completely off base here.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

```
My App.js code-

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import AddItem from './AddItem';
import SingleItem from './singleItem';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dataSource: [],
      isLoaded: false,
    }
    this.onAdd = this.onAdd.bind(this);
    this.onEditSubmit = this.onEditSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataSource();

  }

  getDataSource() {
    return fetch('https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error)); //to catch the errors if any
  }
onAdd( name, likes) {
  const dataSource = this.getDataSource();
    dataSource.then(json => {
      json.push({
        name,
        likes
      });
      this.setState({dataSource: json});
    });
}


onEditSubmit (name, likes, originalName) {
    let dataSource = this.getdataSource();

    dataSource = dataSource.map((dataSource) => {
      if (dataSource.name === originalName) {
        dataSource.name = name;
        dataSource.likes = likes;
      }
      return dataSource;
    });
    this.setState({dataSource});
}

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
      <h1>What is in My Fridge?</h1>

      <AddItem
        onAdd={this.onAdd}
      />

          {this.state.dataSource.map((dataSource) => (
            <SingleItem
              key={dataSource.name}
              name={dataSource.name}
              likes={dataSource.likes}
              onEditSubmit={this.onEditSubmit}
            />
          ))};




      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

my AddItem.js component code-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class AddItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.onAdd(this.nameInput.value, this.likesInput.value);
    this.nameInput.value = '';
    this.likesInput.value = '';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
      <h3>Add Beer</h3>
        <input placeholder="Name" ref={nameInput => this.nameInput = nameInput} />
        <input placeholder="Likes" ref={likesInput => this.likesInput = likesInput}/>
        <button>Add</button>
        <hr />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default AddItem;
```

my singleItem.js code -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


class SingleItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isEdit: false
    };


    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this);
    this.onEditSubmit = this.onEditSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  onEdit() {
    this.setState({ isEdit: true });
  }

  onEditSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.props.onEditSubmit(this.nameInput.value, this.likesInput.value, this.props.name);
    this.setState({ isEdit: false });

  }

  render() {
    const { name, likes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.isEdit
            ? (
              <form onSubmit={this.onEditSubmit}>
              <input placeholder="Name" ref={nameInput => this.nameInput = nameInput} defaultValue={name}/>
              <input placeholder="Likes" ref={likesInput => this.likesInput = likesInput} defaultValue={likes}/>
              <button>Save</button>
                </form>
            )
            :   (
              <div>
      <li>
        {name} | Likes:  {likes}
      </li>
      <button onClick={this.onEdit}>Edit</button>

       </div>
)
}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your App.js, inside of your onEditSubmit function, you need to correct your camel case in your function call: this.getDataSource() instead if this.getdataSource.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It seems like that took care of that error! Thank you. However, now when I got to submit that edition, I get an error on the same method saying dataSource.map is not a function .

Answer (score 0):

I think your stuff is out of order maybe?  Can you try this?

```
  getDataSource() {
    return fetch('https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          dataSource: responseJson,
        });
        return responseJson;
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error)); //to catch the errors if any
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataSource();

  }
```

Also you would just use put or post if you are editting or creating API request such as:

```
fetch(''https://beer.fluentcloud.com/v1/beer'', {
  method: 'PUT',
  body: 'beer'
})
```

Comment: hmmm. I tried reconfiguring the layout like you suggested. It is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind this function already ?

```
    this.getDataSource= this.getDataSource.bind(this);
```

If you want to make CRUD operations, you are on the way, the `fetch` API will allow you to post and get data from the server.

Here is an example of how to use `fetch` with a `POST` method :

```
var form = new FormData(document.getElementById('login-form'));
fetch("/login", {
  method: "POST",
  body: form
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Damn, I missed this.  He could bind or go es6 with the getDataSource function

Comment: @Chatmalow I tried to bind like suggested. Still throwing the error. That seems like an excellent suggestion. Maybe I am placing it in the wrong method. I added it to the constructor with the rest on the binds.